# Explanation of Bent's Rule

Tags: hybridization, valence-bond-theory

Why does the %s character increase on the orbital with electropositive atom? 
I do not seem to properly grasp this concept. Is this rule based on observation or is there any proof to it? If there is a proof can you guys explain it to me in simple terms? I currently have knowledge of basic quantum mechanics and chemical bonding.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/what-is-bents-rule?rq=1 and http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15671/utility-of-bents-rule-what-can-bents-rule-explain-that-other-qualitative-con?rq=1

Comment: @GeoffHutchison Sorry, I was on mobile and wasn't able to check whether this question has been asked before or not. Thanks for the links :)

Comment: @GeoffHutchison What is the protocol here? Should I delete this question or should I let it stay? Or is there an option to lock this thread?

Comment: @Shubham Yes, you can delete it. If you don't soon it will be on hold and then closed!!