# What is the molecular geometry of NHF₂?

Tags: lewis-structure, vsepr-theory, molecular-structure

I had to draw the molecular shape for $\ce{NHF2}$ as a Trigonal Planar like this
[image: NHF2 Structure Diagram]

But when I check to make sure it was right, I came across a source saying

> NHF2-difluoroammonia--tetrahedral, almost trigonal
>   ([Source 1](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100304194348AA5Rjff))

After looking some more I found a source that now said it was

> Trigonal pyramidal, Bond angle of 107 degrees Bond angle of F-N-F > F-N-H 
>   ([Source 2](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120531081702AAfe0Mg))

Can someone clarify which one it is so I can understand.

Comment: Consider the presence of an electron pair on nitrogen; that should guide you to predict the shape of such as molecule.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can look up the molecule on [chemspider](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.23575.html), where you have a little applet for the 3D structure. Or you can download a coordinate file from [NIST](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/inchi/InChI%3D1S/F2HN/c1-3-2/h3H) and view it in a molecular viewer, like [Avogadro](http://avogadro.cc/wiki/Main_Page). Or keep on reading for some deeper insight.

As Klaus already pointed out, if VSEPR is a valid concept, one would arrive at the conclusion, that the molecule is trigonal pyramidal, like ammonia. I performed a DF-BP86/def2-SVP calculation on this to analyse the electronic structure a bit more.
[image: molecular structure of HNF2]   
[image]
One reason why VSEPR does fail (a lot) is that lone pairs are more stable in orbitals with high s character. Another point that is often observed is that orbitals with higher p character are directed to more electronegative elements (Bent's Rule).<sup>[1,2]</sup> As a result of that, the bond angle between electronegative elements gets smaller. This can be observed here, too. From the ideal sp³ arrangement we would expect an 109.5° angle, but here it is about 5° smaller. As a consequence also the hydrogen-nitrogen-fluorine angle has to decrease. In this case the bond angle becomes much smaller because of an intramolecular hydrogen bond.<sup>[3]</sup>
The NBO analysis consequently builds the same picture:
$$\begin{array}{llll}\hline
\text{type}&\text{main contribution}&\text{other contributions}\\\hline
\sigma\text{-Bd}~\ce{N-F}& 64\%~\ce{F}~(14\% s + 86\% p) & 36\%~\ce{N}~(15\% s + 85\% p) \\
\sigma\text{-Bd}~\ce{N-H}& 68\%~\ce{N}~(25\% s + 75\% p) & 32\%~\ce{H}~(100\% s) \\
\sigma\text{-LP}~\ce{N} & 100\%~\ce{N}~(52\% s + 48\% p) &  \\
\sigma\text{-LP}~\ce{F} & 100\%~\ce{F}~(75\% s + 25\% p) &  \\
\sigma\text{-LP}~\ce{F} & 100\%~\ce{F}~(10\% s + 90\% p) &  \\
\sigma\text{-LP}~\ce{F} & 97\%~\ce{F}~(100\% p) &  2\%~\ce{N}~(7\% s + 93\% p) & 1\%~\ce{F2}~(15\% s + 85\% p)\\\hline
\end{array}$$

The planar (trigonal) structure on this level of theory is about 33 kcal/mol higher in energy. It is the transition state for the [nitrogen inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_inversion), which is therefore very slow.

---

*Notes*:

1. Bent's rule on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bent's_rule)
2. Bent's rule on our network: [Utility of Bent's Rule - What can Bent's rule explain that other qualitative considerations cannot?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/15671/4945)
3. The bond length is much smaller than the sum of the corresponding van der Waals radii, suggesting a hydrogen bond. Compare [A. Bondi *J. Phys. Chem.*, **1964**, *68* (3), pp 441–451](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j100785a001).
   $r_{\mathrm{vdW}}(\ce{HF})=r_{\mathrm{vdW}}(\ce{H})+r_{\mathrm{vdW}}(\ce{F})= (106 + 140)~\mathrm{pm}= 246~\mathrm{pm}$

Comment: what programs did you use in the calculation/analysis for this post?

Comment: @permeakra Gaussian 09, rev. D.01 and the built-in NBO 3.1; pictures are chemcraft.

Comment: I favorited the question because of this answer!

Comment: +1 Martin's work would have been a nice publication a few years back: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00427a013

Comment: @DavePhD Haha, that's true, but a 'few' years back you would not have done it in an hour ;) Thanks for the link, I was looking for a publication, but not quite able to find one in the allotted time.

Comment: @DavePhD Any motivation to nail this analysis with CCSD(T) and a large basis set? Martin and I could knock that sucker out in a few months (the computations I mean). :)

Comment: @LordStryker Knock it out of the park, mate. Large basis set? Go BSL (or is it CBS)! Why not include quadruples?! Seriously, if I had the capacity, I would totally run this...

Answer (score 4):

Assuming for a moment that VSEPR is a valid concept, 
difluoramine ($\ce{NF2H}$) is represented by $\bf{AX_3E_1}$, and so is ammonia ($\ce{NH3}$). Try to walk your way down from there.