# Why do PBr3 and PCl3 have larger bond angles than PH3?

Tags: bond, molecular-structure

According to the Colby Chemistry Database, the bond angle of $\ce{PBr3}$ and $\ce{PCl3}$ are around $101$ degrees, but the bond angle of $\ce{PH3}$ is $92$ degrees. (Source: [PCl3](http://www.colby.edu/chemistry/webmo/PCl3.html) [PBr3](http://www.colby.edu/chemistry/webmo/PBr3.html) [PH3](http://www.colby.edu/chemistry/webmo/PH3.html))

There was a previous question on Stack Exchange about the bond angle difference in $\ce{PF3}$ and $\ce{PH3}$ here: [PF3 and PH3](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35333/why-the-bond-angle-of-ph3-is-lesser-that-that-of-pf3), but the accepted answer mentions back bonding as a factor to increase the bond angle in $\ce{PF3}$. I was skeptical about this answer, because in $\ce{PCl3}$ and $\ce{PBr3}$, there should be less back bonding than in $\ce{PF3}$ because bromine and chlorine are both much larger than fluorine and there will be worse orbital overlap between the halogen. Less back bonding should make the bond angle of $\ce{PCl3}$ and $\ce{PBr3}$ smaller than that of $\ce{PF3}$, if back bonding were the major factor here? In reality, that is not the case. Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The larger angles can simply be explained as a result of repulsion between the larger atoms of $\ce{Br}$ and $\ce{Cl}$. Hydrogen atoms in $\ce{PH3},$ as the are so small, experience less repulsion as compared to $\ce{Br}$ atoms in $\ce{PBr3}$ or $\ce{Cl}$ atoms in $\ce{PCl3},$ therefore the larger bond angles in $\ce{PBr3}$ and $\ce{PCl3}.$