# Organic chemistry, hybridization concept

Tags: hybridization

Hybridization of phenyl cation and venyl[sic] vinyl cation and acetylene cation ,I am totally confused , I think that the hybridization of both phenyl and the venyl cation is SP , I think that in both cases the positive charge remains at pz orbital , but my tuition teacher said me that the hybridization of phenyl cation is SP2 but the hybridization of venyl cation is SP now please give me a proper explanation of hybridization of those cations

Comment: This may help: keep in mind what shape a phenyl ring has. Your $sp$ hybridization would correspond to one of those carbons in the hexagon having an 180-degree angle instead of a 120-degree angle.

Comment: Putting it another way, in the formula cosθ=(p−1)/p ,where p stands for % p character and θ stands for the bond angle, see what amount of approximate p-character you are obtaining if you put θ as 120°(which is the bond angle of phenyl cation) and then try to see what type of s-p mixing would justify this result. Remember, hybridization is just a mathematical construct,and it can be moulded so as to justify a certain geometry

Comment: @YUSUFHASAN , please tell the orbital in which the +ve charge resides in every cation

Comment: A positive charge isn't like a lone pair which would reside in a particular orbital; it is the absence of electrons in orbitals that gives a positive charge

Comment: So please say the vacant orbitals of the concern carbocations

Comment: It is becoming customary to write literally nonsensical sentence. Unless you resumed the question in your own way. There is not hybridisation of pheyl cation etc. Unless hybridisation refers to another level of specificity. This made clear, tgen the other comments gives you the way of thinking.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10509/why-are-vinylic-and-arylic-carbocations-highly-unstable https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38093/do-vinyl-cations-adopt-a-classical-or-non-classical-structure

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/49648/is-the-phenyl-cation-or-ethynylium-more-stable